# Алгоритм. Наиболее оптимальный шаг чтобы произвести выстрел в дуэли

Tags: алгоритм, математика, логика

Помогите решить задачу, понять сам алгоритм, и в каком направлении двигаться.

Поединок.

Поединок начинается с того, что оба соперника располагаются на расстоянии двадцати шагов друг от друга, и каждому дается только один выстрел и, соответственно. В течение поединка соперники ходят по очереди, каждый ход участник может либо сделать шаг вперед, либо произвести выстрел. Чем ближе находятся соперники друг к другу, тем выше шанс попадания. При этом шанс попадания увеличивается линейно, начиная с определенного значения в начале поединка до 100% при полном сближении.
Сложность состоит в том, что если вы сделаете выстрел и промахнетесь, соперник будет иметь право сделать необходимое количество шагов, подойти к вам вплотную, и выстрелить с гарантированным попаданием, что обеспечит ему победу.
Создайте алгоритм, который, отталкиваясь от заданных значений шансов попадания для вас и соперника в начале поединка, будет определять номер шага когда вам нужно произвести выстрел для получения наиболее высоких шансов на победу.

Входящие параметры:
Значения шансов попадания в начале поединка для каждого участника(например 0.1 и 02, тогда для первого участника с каждым шагом шанс попадания будет расти на 0.09 а для второго на 0.08), а также номер участника, который ходит первым.

Выходные данные:
Наиболее оптимальный шаг для произведения выстрела.

Comment: Что у вас есть скажите? Какие нароботки? Или вы хотите, чтобы тут за вас решили все с 0-я?

Comment: Собственно мне не нужен сам код приложения, хотелось бы понять саму логику, как можно оценить когда стоит делать выстрел а когда нет и тд? Я предположил что при шансах менее 50% делать вы стрел не стоит так вероятность проигрыша слишком большая, но и не стоит ждать пока вероятность попадания соперника будет выше 50%...Но не уверен ли я размышляю.

Comment: Тогда уберите тэги `java c++` ведь они тут зачем? Я лично подумал, что вам нужно именно решение.

Comment: по описанию игра больше напоминает покер и решать ее лучше не математическими средставми (а это как бы к программированию немного боком), а психологией. Но если нужно именно программирование, то тут нужно делать моделирование и проганять по много раз. Но думаю, что результат будет один  - чем ближе подойти, тем лучше. Поэтому, мой ответ - самый правильный вариант - бежать и не вступать в дуэли.

Comment: неправильные у Вас задачи. Они прививают плохие желания

Comment: Решаете задачу от последнего шага назад. Когда остался один шаг - выгоднее стрельнуть, чем шагнуть, поскольку если шагнуть - стрельнет противник и попадет со 100%. Значит за один шаг до цели - выгоднее стрелять и попасть с вероятностью скажем 90%. Тогда противнику за два шага до цели выгоднее стрельнуть и попасть с вероятностью 80%, чем шагнуть и быть пораженным с вероятностью 90%, тогда вам за 3 шага до цели... и т.д.

Comment: Постановка задачи какая-то некорректная: если противники стреляют по очереди, то всегда выигрывает тот кто стреляет первым - подходит до нулевого расстояния и убивает соперника. Переформулируйте условия

Comment: @Barmaley не, 2 стреляет раньше. Всё нормально с условием.

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить суть вот этого: `Y > 1 - V[0][i+1]`?
Получается игрок стреляет, если вероятность попадания больше промаха противника на следующем шаге?
И вот этого `V[0][i] = 1 - Y;`.
При вероятности `0.1` и `0.8` у меня почему-то получается, что Второй игрок может стрелять когда угодно, а первый только на 10 шаге.

Answer (score 1):

Решать задачу будем с конца. По дополненному условию делаем вывод, что игра длится ровно 10 ходов (если больше - подправите константу). Кто победит на последнем ходу - понятно - тот кто первый ходит. Дальше просто игра с вероятностями. Код на С++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x[] = {0.1, 0.8};
    double d[] = {0.09, 0.02};

    double V[2][11];
    double b[2][11];

    V[0][10] = 1;
    b[0][10] = 10;
    V[1][10] = 0;
    b[0][10] = -1; //no way

    for (int i=9;i>=0;i--){
        double X = x[0] + d[0]*i;
        double Y = x[1] + d[1]*i;
        if (Y > 1 - V[0][i+1]){ //2 shot
            V[1][i] = Y;
            V[0][i] = 1 - Y;
            b[1][i] = i;
            b[0][i] = 10;
        } else {  //2 no shot
            V[1][i] = V[1][i+1];
            V[0][i] = V[0][i+1];
            b[1][i] = b[1][i+1];
            b[0][i] = b[0][i+1];        
        }

        if (X > 1 - V[1][i]){ // 1 shot
            V[1][i] = 1 - X;
            V[0][i] = X;
            b[1][i] = 10;
            b[0][i] = i;        

        }

    }

    cout << V[0][0]<<" "<<b[0][0]<<endl;
    cout << V[1][0]<<" "<<b[1][0]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ответ для примера

```
0.48 10
0.52 4
```

Т.е. 2 игрок должен стрелять на 4 ходу с шансом 0,52 ну а первый стреляет только в упор.

Почему ответ с  50% был не верен. При

```
double x[] = {0.1, 0.8};
double d[] = {0.09, 0.02};
```

Явно 1 игроку стоит стрелять но не сразу (так у него всего 10% на победу а подождав 1 ход с шансом 19%).

Comment: Спс, я так и размышлял, но решил убедиться, в интернете не нашел подобных задач. Только получается вероятность попадания противника можно не учитывать, а она зачем-то есть в условиях.

Comment: @Alex стоп. А они различны? Вообще-то тогда нужно. Ответ дополню.

Comment: @Alex обновил ответ.

Comment: Тут немного нестыковка получается, так как приближение зависит только от одного участника, а не от двух. Грубо говоря, если первый подойдет к центру, а второй, скажем, останется на месте (или, например, пропустит один ход, выстрелив и промахнувшись, из-за чего застрянет на 8-9 шаге), вероятность попадания первого будет равна 1, как если бы они оба подошли к центру и стояли вплотную. Но это не так: между ними будет еще 1-2 шага.

Comment: @Николай ну на самом деле что будет в случае промаха - нас вообще не интересует. А стоять на месте по условию нельзя.

Comment: Стоять на месте нельзя, да. Но я же пишу, если противник просто не походит из-за того, что выстрелит и промахнется, вероятности уже будут неверны, так как со своей стороны-то он шаг не сделал, а это не учтено при расчете.

Comment: @Николай пишу ещё раз. Если противник не попал (или мы не попали) то игра на этом заканчивается. Нету уже никаких вероятностей дальше.