# алгоритм поединка (вероятности)

Tags: java, алгоритм

У меня вопрос по этой задаче:

> Поединок начинается с того, что оба соперника располагаются на
>   расстоянии двадцати шагов друг от друга, и каждому дается только один
>   выстрел и, соответственно. В течение поединка соперники ходят по
>   очереди, каждый ход участник может либо сделать шаг вперед, либо
>   произвести выстрел. Чем ближе находятся соперники друг к другу, тем
>   выше шанс попадания. При этом шанс попадания увеличивается линейно,
>   начиная с определенного значения в начале поединка до 100% при полном
>   сближении. Сложность состоит в том, что если вы сделаете выстрел и
>   промахнетесь, соперник будет иметь право сделать необходимое
>   количество шагов, подойти к вам вплотную, и выстрелить с
>   гарантированным попаданием, что обеспечит ему победу. Создайте
>   алгоритм, который, отталкиваясь от заданных значений шансов попадания
>   для вас и соперника в начале поединка, будет определять номер шага
>   когда вам нужно произвести выстрел для получения наиболее высоких
>   шансов на победу.
>
> Входящие параметры: Значения шансов попадания в начале поединка для
>   каждого участника(например 0.1 и 02, тогда для первого участника с
>   каждым шагом шанс попадания будет расти на 0.09 а для второго на
>   0.08), а также номер участника, который ходит первым.
>
> Выходные данные: Наиболее оптимальный шаг для произведения выстрела.

Я сделал следуйщий код, но вывода не последовало. Где-то на форуме видел совет, что нужно стрелять когда вероятность попасть на этом шаге больше чем вероятность попасть у противника на следуюшем

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input start probabilities:");
        double first = scanner.nextDouble();
        double second = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Input number of player starting first:");
        int player = scanner.nextInt();

        double[] prob = {first, second};
        double[] resprob = {((1 - first) / 10 ),((1 - second) / 10)};

        for(int i = 9;i<=0;i--){
            if((resprob[0]*i)+prob[0]>(resprob[1]*i-1)+prob[1]){
                System.out.println("The optimal shot range is:"+i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/725709/1984

Comment: Я видел этот пост, но решение там не правильное. Постоянно выводит один и тот же результат для любого набора входных данных. Плюс там нет даже ввода даных и распределения в зависимости от того кто из игроков начнёт первым двигаться.

Comment: Стрелять надо первым :) оксиома

Comment: Ну или действительно ввести какой-то фиксированый параметр вероятности при котором начинать стрелять. Не понимаю я вообщем эту задачу. Такое чуство что её не дописали)

Comment: Задача хорошая... надеюсь, я с ней разобрался... ну а Вам уж решать :)  По текущему решению могу только заметить, что у 2-го соперника на его первом ходе расстояние уже на 1/20 меньше, это надо учитывать в формуле. Попробуйте написать некоторый ряд вероятностей попадания для каждого соперника на очередном этапе, после этого стратегия становится понятной.

Comment: У вам тоже нет распределения зависимостей - переменная player не используется.

Comment: Формула непонятная. Для чего -1 во второй части?

Comment: В цикле if? Если да, то там я попытался сравнивать текущую вероятность попадания первого лучника со следующей вероятностю попадания у второго.

Comment: Да, в цикле. Там правая часть сравнения всегда будет меньше единицы. Вам нужно заключить ``i-1`` в скобки (судя по последнему комментарию) - ``(resprob[1]*(i-1))+prob[1])``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, то вот решение:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input start probabilities:");
    double first = scanner.nextDouble();
    double second = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Input number of player starting first:");
    int player = scanner.nextInt();
    int n =20;
    double[] prob = {first, second};
    double[] resProb = {((1 - first) / n ),((1 - second) / n)};

    if(player==1) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
            if ((resProb[0] * i) + prob[0] > (1 - resProb[1] * (i + 1) - prob[1])) {
                System.out.println("The optimal shot range is:" + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if(prob[1]>1-resProb[0]-prob[0]){
            n=n-1;
            System.out.println("The optimal shot range is: " + n);
        }
        else{
            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
                if ((resProb[0] * i) + prob[0] > (1 - resProb[1] * (i + 2) - prob[1])) {
                    System.out.println("The optimal shot range is: " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Первый цикл решает задачу, если мы ходим первыми.
Дальше мы проверяем: если второму выгодно выстрелить на первом шаге, то тогда он выстрелит и мы будем стрелять ему в упор, если он не стреляет, то задача превращается в первую, но на шаг меньше.